# Compilation error with bounded wildcards using Java classes in Scala

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, scala-java-interop, bounded-wildcard

In Java, we have defined an `ObservableCollection.java` like this:

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> implements Collection<T> {

   public SubscriptionHandle onElementAdded(Consumer<T> onAdded) {
     // ... 
   }
}
```

And an `AgentService.java` that returns an ObservableCollection:

```
public interface AgentService {

    ObservableCollection<? extends Agent> getAgents();

}
```

Now, I am trying to use this `ObservableCollection.java` in a **Scala** project like this:

```
  def test(service: AgentService): Unit = {
    val onAdded: Consumer[_ <: Agent] = ???
    service.getAgents.onElementAdded(onAdded)
  }
```

Trying this results in the following compilation error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.function.Consumer[_$1] where type _$1 <: com.xxxx.xx.xx.agent.Agent
 required: java.util.function.Consumer[?0] where type ?0 <: com.xxxx.xx.xx.agent.Agent
    service.getAgents.onElementAdded(onAdded)
                                     ^
one error found
```

This does not make much sense to me. Is there a way I can get this running?

**Edit:** Using a `Cosumer[Agent]` results in the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.function.Consumer[com.xxxx.xx.xx.agent.Agent]
 required: java.util.function.Consumer[?0] where type ?0 <: com.kuka.cc.si.agent.Agent
Note: com.xxxx.xx.xx.agent.Agent >: ?0, but Java-defined trait Consumer is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ?0`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    service.getAgents.onElementAdded(onAdded)
                                     ^
one error found
```

Comment: Is the error real or just in some IDE? - What happens is you have a `Consumer[Agent]`? - What happens if you do a dirty cast like `service.getAgents.asInstanceOf[ObservableCollection[Agent]]` _(plus the previous point)_?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It's real.

Comment: Yes, the error is real. Regarding the usage of `Consumer[Agent]`: see edited question. With the dirty cast it works, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is not in Scala-Java interop. The following Scala code doesn't compile either

```scala
import java.util.function.Consumer
import java.util

trait Agent
trait SubscriptionHandle
trait AgentService {
  def getAgents: ObservableCollection[_ <: Agent]
}
trait ObservableCollection[T] extends util.Collection[T] {
  def onElementAdded(onAdded: Consumer[T]): SubscriptionHandle
}

def test(service: AgentService): Unit = {
  val onAdded: Consumer[_ <: Agent] = ???
  val agents: ObservableCollection[_ <: Agent] = service.getAgents
  agents.onElementAdded(onAdded)
//                      ^^^^^^^
}

//type mismatch;
// found   : java.util.function.Consumer[_$2] where type _$2 <: App.Agent
// required: java.util.function.Consumer[_$3]
```

You misuse existential types (wildcard generics). The following code can't compile

```scala
trait X[T]
trait Y[T] {
  def foo(x: X[T]) = ???
}
val x: X[_] = ???
val y: Y[_] = ???
y.foo(x) // doesn't compile
```

Both `x` and `y` have existential types but `foo` accepts `x` of type `X[T]`, where `T` must be the same as `T` in the type of `y`, i.e. `Y[T]`, so you can't guarantee that `T` are the same.

One way to fix compilation is to add generics to `AgentService`

```scala
trait Agent
trait SubscriptionHandle
trait AgentService[T <: Agent] {
  def getAgents: ObservableCollection[T]
}
trait ObservableCollection[T] extends util.Collection[T] {
  def onElementAdded(onAdded: Consumer[T]): SubscriptionHandle
}

def test[T <: Agent](service: AgentService[T]): Unit = {
  val onAdded: Consumer[T] = ???
  val agents: ObservableCollection[T] = service.getAgents
  agents.onElementAdded(onAdded)
}
```

or to its method

```scala
trait Agent
trait SubscriptionHandle
trait AgentService {
  def getAgents[T <: Agent]: ObservableCollection[T]
}
trait ObservableCollection[T] extends util.Collection[T] {
  def onElementAdded(onAdded: Consumer[T]): SubscriptionHandle
}

def test[T <: Agent](service: AgentService): Unit = {
  val onAdded: Consumer[T] = ???
  val agents: ObservableCollection[T] = service.getAgents
  agents.onElementAdded(onAdded)
}
```